# Using scala-eclipse for spark

Tags: eclipse, scala, apache-spark

Could some please help me on how to use the scala-eclipse IDE for spark ?
I came across this link - http://syndeticlogic.net/?p=311. But I am unable to follow it. 
I entered the command -  mvn -Phadoop2 eclipse:clean eclipse:eclipse inside the spark directory after a long list of downloads it gave me some error. Please help. Thanks

### Below is the error i received

```
Reactor Summary:
[INFO] 
[INFO] Spark Project Parent POM .......................... SUCCESS [5:22.386s]
[INFO] Spark Project Core ................................ SUCCESS [17:20.807s]
[INFO] Spark Project Bagel ............................... FAILURE [2.159s]
[INFO] Spark Project GraphX .............................. SKIPPED
[INFO] Spark Project ML Library .......................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Spark Project Streaming ........................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Spark Project Tools ............................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Spark Project Catalyst ............................ SKIPPED
[INFO] Spark Project SQL ................................. SKIPPED
[INFO] Spark Project Hive ................................ SKIPPED
[INFO] Spark Project REPL ................................ SKIPPED
[INFO] Spark Project Assembly ............................ SKIPPED
[INFO] Spark Project External Twitter .................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Spark Project External Kafka ...................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Spark Project External Flume ...................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Spark Project External ZeroMQ ..................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Spark Project External MQTT ....................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Spark Project Examples ............................ SKIPPED
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 25:15.115s
[INFO] Finished at: Wed May 07 15:27:51 GMT+05:30 2014
[INFO] Final Memory: 22M/81M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[WARNING] The requested profile "hadoop2" could not be activated because it does not exist.
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-remote-resources-plugin:1.5:process (default) on project spark-bagel_2.10: Failed to resolve dependencies for one or more projects in the reactor. Reason: Missing:
[ERROR] ----------
[ERROR] 1) org.apache.spark:spark-core_2.10:jar:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] Try downloading the file manually from the project website.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] Then, install it using the command:
[ERROR] mvn install:install-file -DgroupId=org.apache.spark -DartifactId=spark-core_2.10 -Dversion=1.0.0-SNAPSHOT -Dpackaging=jar -Dfile=/path/to/file
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] Alternatively, if you host your own repository you can deploy the file there:
[ERROR] mvn deploy:deploy-file -DgroupId=org.apache.spark -DartifactId=spark-core_2.10 -Dversion=1.0.0-SNAPSHOT -Dpackaging=jar -Dfile=/path/to/file -Durl=[url] -DrepositoryId=[id]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] Path to dependency:
[ERROR] 1) org.apache.spark:spark-bagel_2.10:jar:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT
[ERROR] 2) org.apache.spark:spark-core_2.10:jar:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] ----------
[ERROR] 1 required artifact is missing.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] for artifact:
[ERROR] org.apache.spark:spark-bagel_2.10:jar:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] from the specified remote repositories:
[ERROR] maven-repo (http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2, releases=true, snapshots=false),
[ERROR] apache-repo (https://repository.apache.org/content/repositories/releases, releases=true, snapshots=false),
[ERROR] jboss-repo (https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/repositories/releases, releases=true, snapshots=false),
[ERROR] mqtt-repo (https://repo.eclipse.org/content/repositories/paho-releases, releases=true, snapshots=false),
[ERROR] cloudera-repo (https://repository.cloudera.com/artifactory/cloudera-repos, releases=true, snapshots=false),
[ERROR] apache.snapshots (http://repository.apache.org/snapshots, releases=false, snapshots=true),
[ERROR] central (http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2, releases=true, snapshots=false)
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] After correcting the problems, you can resume the build with the command
[ERROR]   mvn <goals> -rf :spark-bagel_2.10
```

Answer (score 3):

This is because there is no profile called hadoop2 in the pom.xml. The closest matches are hadoop-2.2,hadoop-2.3 etc.

You can run the following

```
mvn -Phadoop-2.2 eclipse:clean eclipse:eclipse
```

or you may run  `'mvn help:all-profiles'` to list all the profiles and use one from it

Answer (score 0):

If you want to contribute to the Apache Spark project, then

- Go to spark home and run sbt/sbt eclipse
- In Scala IDE, Select File |    Import | Existing Projects into Workspace.
- Select root directory    :MY_SPARK_HOME
- Select Search for Nested Projects
- Select the    projects that you want
- Do not select "Copy projects into workspace".

If you want to use the spark libraries in an application that you are using then,
- You can create a jar using the sbt/sbt assembly command and then add that jar as a library to your application project

Also refer to the eclipse documentation here at: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/SPARK/Contributing+to+Spark#ContributingtoSpark-Eclipse